# Returning to login screen with forms authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, webforms

I have a web application using web forms, it has a login screen which works fine.

The problem I have is that when you have the screen open and the session expires, if you click a link inside that opens a popup, the popup will open but it will be redirected to the login page. Then if you sign in within the popup it redirects to the home page within the tiny window and you basically need to start again.

I would like to fix this so if you try to do anything and you need to sign in again that either you are returned to the login screen within the main window then back to the previous page or better still if you could open a login form within a modal window or something so you can sign in before continuing that would be great as it would not interrupt the user.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that the browser has no idea about when the session has expired so you would need to do one of the following options (I'm sure there are others):

1. Add a Javascript timer on the page with the same or slightly shorter time than the session timeout (20 mins by default). Before opening a pop up check if the timer has expired and redirect the user with javascript to the login page if it has.
2. Check for session timeout via a behind-the-scenes AJAX call before displaying the pop up form. Redirect the users via javascript if the session is expired.

With either of these options you could request (probably a modified) login page to display in the modal window if the session is timed out based on the javascript timer expiration or result of the ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

you can return to that page from where you thrown to login page by getting `returnurl` from querystring on login page.

```
if return url blank
   redirect to default page
else 
   redirect to previous page
```

Comment: It already has a return URL, I can see it is the correct one but after logging back it it returns to default.aspx and ignores the previous return URL.

Comment: use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(username,false);

Comment: Where do I include this?

Comment: when you have to redirect user after authentication use above method

Answer (score 0):

The Idea could be remove your page from authentication part using `Location Path` of the `web.config` file.

```
<location path="YourPage.aspx">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Check the `Session` variable there if find null then use java-script to close the window and redirect the `opener` to login page.

### YourPage.aspx.cs

PageLoad method

```
if(Session["userid"]==null)
{
    Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.close()");
    Response.Write("window.opener.document.location = url.");
    Response.Write("</script>");

}
```

close window in redirect the parent page to login.

**Note that this is not a working example this is just an idea**

Comment: Even if I use this I am using the authentication cookie across all pages so that would still expire anyway.